# Passing functions to props.children

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have looked at countless stack overflow questions to solve this but none of them seem to work for me. It could be I'm not understanding something but I follow what the solutions are and still get the error I have or worse errors.

I have my layout component here:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

// Sentry
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

// Material UI
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

// Components
import NavBar from "./../components/NavBar";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
}));

function MainLayout(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [snackBarOpen, setSnackBarOpen] = useState(false);
    const [snackBarMessage, setSnackBarMessage] = useState(null);

    const handleErrors = (error, message) => {
        setSnackBarMessage(message)
        setSnackBarOpen(true)

        Sentry.captureMessage(error)
    }

    const handleSnackBarClose = () => {
        setSnackBarOpen(false);
    }

    const children = React.cloneElement(
        React.Children.only(props.children), {
            handleErrors: handleErrors
        }
    )

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <NavBar />
            <main className={classes.main}>
                { children }
            </main>
            <Snackbar
                open={snackBarOpen}
                onClose={handleSnackBarClose}
                message={snackBarMessage}
                anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'right' }}
                action={
                    <Fragment>
                        <IconButton size="small" aria-label="close" color="inherit" onClick={handleSnackBarClose}>
                            <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Fragment>
                }
            />
        </div>
    );
  }

  export default MainLayout;
```

Now when I load the page it loads however I have this error in console:

```
*Warning: React does not recognize the `handleErrors` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `handleerrors` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.*
```

Also when I have an error thrown on the child element it errors out. Here is one of my child elements:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

// Sentry
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

// AG Grid
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

// Material UI
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import Snackbar from '@material-ui/core/Snackbar';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';

// Components
import NavBar from "./../components/NavBar";
import { graphQLQuery } from "../utils/queries";
import MainLayout from "./../layouts/MainLayout";
import { mapGridColumns } from "../utils/helper-functions";

// CSS
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    gridContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    }
}));

function DivisionsView(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [divisions, setDivisions] = useState([]);
    const [agGridRowData, setAgGridRowData] = useState([]);
    const [agGridColumnDefs, setAgGridColumnDefs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchDivisions() {
            const query = `{
                division {
                  record_id
                  region_id
                  division_id
                  division
                  division_name
                }
              }`;
            let divisionsFetched = await graphQLQuery(query);

            if(divisionsFetched.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
                props.handleErrors(divisionsFetched.errors, 'There was an error fetching divisions. Please try again in a few minutes.');
            }

            if(divisionsFetched.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
                setDivisions(divisionsFetched.data)
            }
        }

        fetchDivisions();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(divisions.hasOwnProperty('division') && divisions.division.length > 0) {
            let headerNames = mapGridColumns(divisions.division[0]);

            setAgGridColumnDefs(headerNames);
            setAgGridRowData(divisions.division);
        }
    }, [divisions])

    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <div className={classes.gridContainer}>
                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={agGridColumnDefs}
                    rowData={agGridRowData}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        </MainLayout>
    );
  }

  export default DivisionsView;
```

When it errors below is displayed:

```
TypeError: props.handleErrors is not a function
```

Could someone help me understand why other answers/tutorial say to use the React.Clone method and pass the functions into it but it doesnt work for me and then also the functions are not available on the children.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the prop `handleErrors` to `<div className={classes.gridContainer}>` by cloning the children.

If you want to add this prop to your `AgGridReact`component, remove the div.

Comment: So what your saying is I cannot add that and use it in the effects?

Comment: No, i'm saying that `<div className={classes.gridContainer} handleErrors={handleErrors} />`  is not a valid Dom element

Comment: Oh ok, I get that part. I am not trying to pass this function to any element. I just need the function passed to use in the component will mount part of the useEffect in DivisionsView.js